# Why is Slack integration failing some time after a successful integration?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm having some trouble with Slack integrations with my Dialogflow agents that I hope someone can help me with. I have several agents that I've successfully connected a bot to and successfully interacted with. After some amount of time, usually about half a day, the POST requests that notify my webhook of a new message will no longer include any identifying information about the user or source of the query. Please see the screenshots below:

One is a normal Dialogflow POST requst with the original source message from slack. The other just has {source: "agent"} and the query, but no ID numbers or timestamps at all.

[image: Bad][image: Good]

Answer (score 0):

A `source` value of `agent` indicates that the query came from Dialogflow's simulator (the way you can try out your agent's responses in the Dialogflow console.  More information on the Dialogflow simulator is here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/simulator

If you don't provide information on the entities required when querying in the simulator, entity information won't be included in the webhook request sent to your backend.